# Массив с поиском по ключу Android

Tags: android, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, массив, контейнер, что угодно, который будет хранить данные в формате "ключ, значение", и соответственно поиск по этому ключу.
Ключ будет Long и будет хранить дату (день, месяц, год, остальное нули).
Значение - Объект опредленного класса 
Смысл в том, чтобы как можно быстрее считать информацию за дату, чем перебегать циклом весь массив. 
Поискал в интернете, нашел SparceArray, однако не смог правильно записать его в Parcelable. Имеется процедура writeSparseArray, который принимает на вход SparseArray val, однако подружить их я не смог.

Comment: use HashMap Luke

Comment: на самом деле, любой `Map`. не обязательно `HashMap`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему нельзя сделать так:

```
Map<Long, SomeObject> data = new HashMap<Long, SomeObject>;
```

и получить value `data.get('keyValue')`? 
Ключ нужен для того чтобы получить именно тот объект, который соответствует ключу.

Что вобще нужно сделать?

Comment: Дело в том, что Android Studio настоятельно мне рекомендует пользоваться классом SparceArray, ссылаясь на то, что он является альтернативой классу Map и его производным. Но примеров этого класса в инете почти нет

Comment: @АрсенШогенов студия такая студия. Предлагаю сделать вид, что вы этого её предложения не замечаете.

Comment: Какое максимальное количество объектов будет лежать в контейнере?

В SparseArray есть метод get(int key), который делает тоже самое что и у HashMap/

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [LongSparceArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LongSparseArray.html). В этой структуре доступ по ключу будет происходить за константное время. Вставка тоже осуществляется быстро.

Использование такое:

```
LongSparseArray<YourObject> yourArray = new LongSparseArray();

// если ключи будут поступать в произвольном порядке
yourArray.put(key, typeOfPayment);

// если ключи будут поступать по возрастанию
yourArray.append(key, typeOfPayment);

//доступ
yourArray.get(key);
```

Если заранее известен размер массива, то можно передать этот размер через конструктор.

Comment: это я усвоил, однако у меня не получилось сохранить экземпляр в Parcelable c помощью writeSparseArray. Примеров интернете не нахожу

Answer (score 0):

Не то?

```
HashMap newmap = new HashMap();
.........
List list.addAll(newmap.keySet());
if (lista.contains(myKey)) {
.....
}
```

Comment: зачем тут вообще список-то?

Comment: @metalurgus для .contains. С нативным Set придется городить поиск в цикле, чего автор хотел избежать

Comment: Нет, не придется. У `Map` есть `containsKey`

Comment: @metalurgus чортъ. Ведь и правда.